Is it wrong to use HttpClientFactory in a singleton service?
I read this article about HttpClientFactory. But i couldn't find a answer for my question. Is it bad approach to use HttpClientFactory in a singleton service to send request to somewhere?
My Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<HttpRequestDelegatingHandler>();


builder.Services.AddHttpClient("test", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpRequestDelegatingHandler>();

And my Test Service:
public class TestService
{
    public Guid InstanceId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    private readonly **IHttpClientFactory _factory;**
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

     public TestService(IHttpClientFactory factory, ILogger<TestController> logger)
    {
        **_factory = factory;**
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        // Get the scoped service's ID
        _logger.LogInformation("Service ID in controller {InstanceId}", InstanceId);

        // Retrieve an instance of the test client, and send a request
        var client = _factory.CreateClient("test");
        var result = await client.GetAsync("posts");

        // Just return a response, we're not interested in this bit for now
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
} 

I created a delegating handler to understand what is going on and i didn't notice any issues.

It is fine to use IHttpClientFactory inside a Singleton service, As a side point, all HttpClient instances that are created by the client factory are meant to be short-lived, then better to use using statement like this:
public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        //...

        // make sure the httpclient will be disposed
        using var client = _factory.CreateClient("test");
        var result = await client.GetAsync("posts");

        // ...
    }

Please consider reading this MS doc as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use

Thanks for your answer. But in this MS document, it gives an example with transient service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#basic-usage
Which one is more efficient?

MS recommends using Typed clients but it will add service as Transient, but in your case the best case is using Named Clients as you did it.
